# how to replay pcap file on wired speed to an NIC

Tags: networking, pcap, replay

I want to replay network packets from pcap file to a specific NIC at wire speed. Trex is useful but the original packets are sent in a very low speed. how to ignore the timestamp and send packet in a very high speed (10Gbps for example)? If this can be done by Trex, what should I do?